# よりよい回答を求めて回答の承認を保留にしてもいいのでしょうか？

Tags: 討議, 質問の仕方

回答を承認するタイミングには何らかのガイドラインはありますでしょうか。
以下のようなやりかたがあるかと思います。

- 一応問題のない回答を得た時点で承認する
- いくつかの回答がつき、それに対する投票がついた段階でそれを参考にして承認する回答を決める
- より良い回答が得られそうならそれまで待つ

何となくのガイドラインがあるのでしょうか。あるいは個人の判断にまかされているのでしょうか。

より良い回答を求めて回答を承認しないでいることが、回答者に対して失礼に当たらないかどうかがとくに知りたいです。

Comment: related: [回答を承認するとどうなりますか？](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1735/8000)

Comment: タイトル、ぐっと良くなりました。ありがとうございます。
関連する質問の示唆も助かります。

Answer (score 11, accepted):

あまり長期にわたって放置されているとメタで議題にされるかもしれませんが、理由をもって少しの間保留にするのは特に問題ないと思います。

しいて言うなら、「こういう理由でもう少し回答を待ってみます」といったコメントを残しておくと、新たな回答が付きやすいかも・・・？（多分大した違いはないです）

> - いくつかの回答がつき、それに対する投票がついた段階でそれを参考にして承認する回答を決める
> - より良い回答が得られそうならそれまで待つ

「この間は承認すべきでない」ということはないですが、そうしても構わないと思います。

承認はいつでも取り消せますし、最も票を集めた回答を承認すべきというわけでもありません。質問した人の独断で、一番役立った・気に入った回答を承認してもらえればいいかと。